# Extracting data from var within script and download pdf's to folders with python

Tags: javascript, python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape information within a variable from an embedded map on [website](https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/supply-chain-map) that includes geo coordinates and also links of pdf documents which I would like to download into specific folders.

My attempt at trying to get the information within the variable has been unsuccessful so far. Can someone tell me what I am missing out to get the data I need?

This is code I have put together so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests

url = 'https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/supply-chain-map' 
page = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

p = re.compile(r"var locations = .")
data  = soup.find_all("script")
m = p.match(data)
```

I can't seem to be be able to find the matching variable within the script. It seems to be capturing a lot more information that just that variable, which is only supposed to be [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/TgNTaaSC)

Aside from getting the links to download the pdf's by facility, I would like create a `data frame` of the facilities, company name, locations and the geo-coordinates so I can export it to a spreadsheet.

Comment: So you're saying that your regular expression is not providing the intended result? Maybe using a graphical interface for testing your regex will help: www.regex101.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests

url = 'https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/supply-chain-map'
page = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
data = soup.find('script', text=re.compile(r"var locations = ."))
print(re.search('var locations.*', str(data)).group())
```

Output:

```
var locations = [[new google.maps.LatLng(3.778669444,98.68998056), 'Belawan','<table><tr><td><b>Facility Name </b></td><td>&nbsp; : Belawan Refinery and Kernel Crushing Plant</td></tr><tr><td><b>Company Name</b></td><td>&nbsp; : PT SMART TBK</td></tr><tr><td><b>Location </b></td><td>&nbsp; : Belawan</td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><b>Summary Report </b></td><td valign="top">&nbsp; : <ul class="gpoplist"><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/14"  target="_blank">Belawan Summary Q1 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/84"  target="_blank">Belawan Summary Q2 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/154"  target="_blank">Belawan Summary Q3 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/226"  target="_blank">Belawan Summary Q4 2017</a></li></ul></td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><b>Supplying Mills </b></td><td valign="top">&nbsp; : <ul class="gpoplist"><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/15"  target="_blank">Belawan Mill List Q1 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/86"  target="_blank">Belawan Mill List Q2 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/153"  target="_blank">Belawan Mill List Q3 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/225"  target="_blank">Belawan Mill List Q4 2017</a></li></ul></td></tr></table>'],[new google.maps.LatLng(1.684938889,101.4462444), 'Dumai','<table><tr><td><b>Facility Name </b></td><td>&nbsp; : Dumai Bulking Station</td></tr><tr><td><b>Company Name</b></td><td>&nbsp; : PT Ivo Mas Tunggal</td></tr><tr><td><b>Location </b></td><td>&nbsp; : Dumai</td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><b>Summary Report </b></td><td valign="top">&nbsp; : <ul class="gpoplist"><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/16"  target="_blank">Dumai Summary Q1 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/87"  target="_blank">Dumai Summary Q2 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/156"  target="_blank">Dumai Summary Q3 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/228"  target="_blank">Dumai Summary Q4 2017</a></li></ul></td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><b>Supplying Mills </b></td><td valign="top">&nbsp; : <ul class="gpoplist"><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/17"  target="_blank">Dumai Mill List Q1 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/100"  target="_blank">Dumai Mill List Q2 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/155"  target="_blank">Dumai Mill List Q3 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/227"  target="_blank">Dumai Mill List Q4 2017</a></li></ul></td></tr></table>'],[new google.maps.LatLng(0.994694444,100.3734167), 'Padang','<table><tr><td><b>Facility Name </b></td><td>&nbsp; : Incasi Raya Padang Bulking Station</td></tr><tr><td><b>Company Name</b></td><td>&nbsp; : PT Leidong West Indonesia</td></tr><tr><td><b>Location </b></td><td>&nbsp; : Padang</td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><b>Summary Report </b></td><td valign="top">&nbsp; : <ul class="gpoplist"><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/18"  target="_blank">Padang Summary Q1 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/92"  target="_blank">Padang Summary Q2 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/162"  target="_blank">Padang Summary Q3 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/234"  target="_blank">Padang Summary Q4 2017</a></li></ul></td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><b>Supplying Mills </b></td><td valign="top">&nbsp; : <ul class="gpoplist"><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/19"  target="_blank">Padang Mill List  Q1 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/93"  target="_blank">Padang Mill List Q2 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/161"  target="_blank">Padang Mill List Q3 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/233"  target="_blank">Padang Mill List Q4 2017</a></li></ul></td></tr></table>'],[new google.maps.LatLng(1.777694444,101.3532778), 'Lubuk Gaung','<table><tr><td><b>Facility Name </b></td><td>&nbsp; : Lubuk Gaung Refinery and Kernel Crushing Plant</td></tr><tr><td><b>Company Name</b></td><td>&nbsp; : PT Ivo Mas Tunggal</td></tr><tr><td><b>Location </b></td><td>&nbsp; : Lubuk Gaung</td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><b>Summary Report </b></td><td valign="top">&nbsp; : <ul class="gpoplist"><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/78"  target="_blank">Lubuk Gaung Summary Q1 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/88"  target="_blank">Lubuk Gaung Summary Q2 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/158"  target="_blank">Lubuk Gaung Summary Q3 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/230"  target="_blank">Lubuk Gaung Summary Q4 2017</a></li></ul></td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><b>Supplying Mills </b></td><td valign="top">&nbsp; : <ul class="gpoplist"><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/77"  target="_blank">Lubuk Gaung Mills List Q1 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/89"  target="_blank">Lubuk Gaung Mills List Q2 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/157"  target="_blank">Lubuk Gaung Mills List Q3 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/229"  target="_blank">Lubuk Gaung Mills List Q4 2017</a></li></ul></td></tr></table>'],[new google.maps.LatLng(-6.091638889,106.9761111), 'Marunda','<table><tr><td><b>Facility Name </b></td><td>&nbsp; : Marunda Refinery</td></tr><tr><td><b>Company Name</b></td><td>&nbsp; : PT SMART TBK</td></tr><tr><td><b>Location </b></td><td>&nbsp; : Marunda</td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><b>Summary Report </b></td><td valign="top">&nbsp; : <ul class="gpoplist"><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/79"  target="_blank">Marunda Summary Q1 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/90"  target="_blank">Marunda Summary Q2 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/160"  target="_blank">Marunda Summary Q3 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/232"  target="_blank">Marunda Summary Q4 2017</a></li></ul></td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><b>Supplying Mills </b></td><td valign="top">&nbsp; : <ul class="gpoplist"><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/80"  target="_blank">Marunda Mill List Q1 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/91"  target="_blank">Marunda Mill List Q2 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/159"  target="_blank">Marunda Mill List Q3 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/231"  target="_blank">Marunda Mill List Q4 2017</a></li></ul></td></tr></table>'],[new google.maps.LatLng(-7.329972222,112.7615556), 'Surabaya','<table><tr><td><b>Facility Name </b></td><td>&nbsp; : Surabaya Refinery</td></tr><tr><td><b>Company Name</b></td><td>&nbsp; : PT SMART TBK</td></tr><tr><td><b>Location </b></td><td>&nbsp; : Surabaya</td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><b>Summary Report </b></td><td valign="top">&nbsp; : <ul class="gpoplist"><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/24"  target="_blank">Surabaya Summary Q1 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/94"  target="_blank">Surabaya Summary Q2 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/164"  target="_blank">Surabaya Summary Q3 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/236"  target="_blank">Surabaya Summary Q4 2017</a></li></ul></td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><b>Supplying Mills </b></td><td valign="top">&nbsp; : <ul class="gpoplist"><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/25"  target="_blank">Surabaya Mill List Q1 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/95"  target="_blank">Surabaya Mill List Q2 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/163"  target="_blank">Surabaya Mill List Q3 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/235"  target="_blank">Surabaya Mill List Q4 2017</a></li></ul></td></tr></table>'],[new google.maps.LatLng(-5.525611111,105.3526111), 'Tarahan','<table><tr><td><b>Facility Name </b></td><td>&nbsp; : Tarahan Refinery and Kernel Crushing Plant</td></tr><tr><td><b>Company Name</b></td><td>&nbsp; : PT Sumber Indah Perkasa</td></tr><tr><td><b>Location </b></td><td>&nbsp; : Tarahan</td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><b>Summary Report </b></td><td valign="top">&nbsp; : <ul class="gpoplist"><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/26"  target="_blank">Tarahan Summary Q1 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/96"  target="_blank">Tarahan Summary Q2 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/166"  target="_blank">Tarahan Summary Q3 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/238"  target="_blank">Tarahan Q4 2017 Summary</a></li></ul></td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><b>Supplying Mills </b></td><td valign="top">&nbsp; : <ul class="gpoplist"><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/27"  target="_blank">Tarahan Mill List Q1 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/97"  target="_blank">Tarahan Mill List Q2 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/165"  target="_blank">Tarahan Mill List Q3 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/237"  target="_blank">Tarahan Mill List Q4 2017</a></li></ul></td></tr></table>'],[new google.maps.LatLng(-3.271758333,116.1177361), 'Tarjun','<table><tr><td><b>Facility Name </b></td><td>&nbsp; : Tarjun Refinery and Kernel Crushing Plant</td></tr><tr><td><b>Company Name</b></td><td>&nbsp; : PT SMART TBK</td></tr><tr><td><b>Location </b></td><td>&nbsp; : Tarjun</td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><b>Summary Report </b></td><td valign="top">&nbsp; : <ul class="gpoplist"><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/28"  target="_blank">Tarjun Summary Q1 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/98"  target="_blank">Tarjun Summary Q2 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/168"  target="_blank">Tarjun Summary Q3 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/240"  target="_blank">Tarjun Summary Q4 2017</a></li></ul></td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><b>Supplying Mills </b></td><td valign="top">&nbsp; : <ul class="gpoplist"><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/29"  target="_blank">Tarjun Mill List Q1 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/99"  target="_blank">Tarjun Mill List Q2 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/167"  target="_blank">Tarjun Mill List Q3 2017</a></li><li> - <a href="https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/239"  target="_blank">Tarjun Mill List Q4 2017</a></li></ul></td></tr></table>']];
```

Comment: Thank for this, @Ali, do you happen to know how I could download the pdf files using the links? My attempt using `beautifulsoup` only gets me `html` files - e.g https://goldenagri.com.sg/sustainability-dashboard/download-file/getfile/14